# Problem with user defined function

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION testing(id INT, dsc TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE ntxt TEXT;
SET ntxt = dsc;
RETURNS ntxt;
END;
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TEXT' at line 3

What i miss here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot to change the delimiter
2. `RETURN` has an extra `S`

This does work:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION testing(id INT, dsc TEXT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE ntxt TEXT;
    SET ntxt = dsc;
    RETURN ntxt;
END//
```

Comment: DELIMITER was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add `DELIMITER $$` in the very beginning of your script (Standard delimiter is `;`, and it's also used in procedures/functions). For example,

```
 DELIMITER $$
 [CREATE FUNCTION ...... ]
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: why are coders obsessed with the $$ when a single non ; will do - like a # ?

Comment: @f00, I guess you feel better when the alternative delimiter is not likely to appear anywhere else.

Comment: +1. Just for example :) Surely, it can be anything. Personally I prefer `//`. But it seems $$ to be more "common"